# A wall of energy slammed me back during meditation? What was this?

Tags: meditation, energy

2 years ago, I was meditating for about 2 hours a day and was rapidly transitioning to a higher vibration when all of the sudden, I was slammed back by a force of energy back into my chair. Since then I havent been able to get as deep into meditation as I did before then. Im not sure what happened, but feel some kind of a block happened. Has anyone else experienced this or know what happened?

Comment: What was happening up until you reached that wall?  Could you describe your mental state?  Also, what sort of practice were you doing?

Comment: @Laurie Smith-Waterman. Hello and welcome to Buddhism SE. Question has been closed as it does not relate to Buddhism but merely meditation in general. Please edit and clarify further in your post.

Comment: Honestly, this sounds like an encounter with mu.  I think this question could be reopened provided that additional information regarding technique was provided.

Answer (score 3):

If your breathing, body & mind are **currently** functioning normally, I would forget about it because your question is an example of 'attachment', which Buddhism teaches to let go of.

Naturally, I can't say exactly what happened, whether the cause was purely mental (a cathartic emotion); or otherwise purely energetic due to some kind of (non-Buddhist) yogic energy manipulation? But obviously what you regarded as "deep" was merely something unnaturally forced & temporary. It sounds like you pushed to some kind of limit in your energetic-breathing-nervous-system due to non-Buddhist yogic practice.

You should ensure your breathing is currently normal because excessive yogic practises can bring harm to the body, breathing & nervous system.

Buddhist meditation has its foundation in letting-go & non-attachment rather than pushing or manipulating.

Below is an example of a yoga practice called 'pranayama', which is a deliberate controlling of breathing:

[image]